# Another FizzBuzz idiot (yeah I've checked the archives for this question)

Tags: python, python-3.x, fizzbuzz

I'm pretty much a Python newb, and I'm using HackerRank warmups to prepare for a test. HackerRank wanted me to do FizzBuzz which I was sure would be easy because I've written up FizzBuzz before and it worked fine.

Except that they wanted it as a defined function that only returns up to the user inputted number, but still within the constrained range.  So what I have so far looks like this:

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys



#
# Complete the 'fizzBuzz' function below.
#
# The function accepts INTEGER n as parameter.
#

def fizzBuzz(n):
    for i in range(200000):
        x = i + 1
        fizz = x % 3 == 0
        buzz = x % 5 == 0

        if fizz:
            if buzz:
                print('FizzBuzz')
            else:
                print('Fizz')
        elif buzz: 
            print('Buzz')
        else:
            print (x)
        
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    giveMEANumber = int(input())
    fizzBuzz(giveMEANumber)
```

So the upper half gives me the correct range, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to pass the user inputted number as a constraint on the range. I've tried googling this and I've also tried looking at other FizzBuzz questions on the site, but haven't been able to find an answer. FYI the imported modules and the comments came with the code, I didn't add them.

Comment: you're not using the user's number

Comment: `range(n+1)`  will return a range of numbers up to `n`

Comment: `min(num1, num2)` returns the smaller of `num1` and `num2`, which can be used to constrain the numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, Barmar! I actually resolved it by making it `range(n)` and adding this right before the `for` loop: `if n <= 200000:` This solved the problems I was specifically asking about, but I realized later that instead of returning nothing when the user enters 200001, I'd prefer it returns everything up to 200k, so I'll look into min and see how I can use it.

Comment: `range(min(n, 200000))`